# what's the difference between Java windows online Installation and Java windows offline Installation?

Tags: java, windows, ide

For the Online Java Installation, Should I need to connect to the internet all the time while working on IDE? and also After Installation of Java Windows Online, the files required for IDE get stored in local? If it get stored in the local why prefer Java Windows Online over Java Windows Offline?

Comment: These two different installation methods have nothing to do with how you use Java _after_ the installation has completed. They relate to how the installation is performed. See [offline installation notes here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/windows_offline_download.html): "_You do not need to remain connected to the Internet during the installation._". In both cases, Java is installed locally on your machine.

Comment: Where are you finding these online/offline installers of Java?

Comment: For background: See [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) for an online/offline download page (this may be different from the location referred to by you in your question, of course). This is for Java 8 - so, quite old. There are also some very brief ["which should I use?"](https://www.java.com/en/download/which_download.jsp) notes. For more modern versions of Java, consider [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) as one alternative source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Offline version is a huge installation file that includes everything needed for installation.

  It means that the computer doesn't need to be connected to the web during installation of Java.

  This version is ideal for installation on multiple machines, because it only downloads the data once.
- Online version is a small installer program that then needs to download the needed installation files when executed.

  It means that the computer requires a web connection during installation of Java.

  This version is good for installation on only one machine, because it only downloads the data that is actually needed.

Comment: And since OP seems confused: *once the installer has finished running* the installations will be identical: neither one requires the user to be online to actually *run* any Java applications (unless the application itself requires it, obviously).

Answer (score 2):

Online installation expects you to be connected all the time till the installation process is finished, i.e. it needs constant internet connectivity.

Offline installation assumes you're not going to be connected throughout the installation process, so it's a stand-alone installer, simply, once you download the offline installation files, you don't need internet anymore for installation, it is self-sufficient.